# how can i make it not resize the elements when browser size is changed?

Tags: html, css

So when i make the browser smaller you will see what happens to the menubar and the dropdown menu make sure you make it full page when you start making the browser smaller so therefore how can i stop that from happening or another solution if there is any? and please don't mind the heading I'm not making a legit website and get rid of the negative votes please it's bugging me.

The html5 coding has a .current class please don't mind that as well i haven't done anything to the class yet and here's a fully working demo of the website.

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
#Mainnav ul li a{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 33%;
 background-color: #CDCDCD;
 border-radius: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 25%;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#Mainnav a:hover {
 background-color: #666;
}
#Top {
 color: #FFB700;
 font-family: black-ops-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: x-large;
}
#Mainnav ul li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width:33%;
 list-style-type:none;
}
#Mainnav ul ul li {
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 display:block;
}
#Mainnav ul ul a {
 padding-right:40px;
 margin-top:10px;
 text-align:right;
 
}
#Mainnav ul ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 35px;
 top: 131px;
}
#Mainnav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>The Website</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/black-ops-one:n4:default;source-sans-pro:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Heading-->
<header id="Top"><h1>ShayanShow</h1></header>
<!--MenuBar-->
<nav id="Mainnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
<a href="#">About Us</a></li><li>
<a href="#">Contacts</a><ul>
<!--DropDown List-->
<li><a href="#">FaceBook</a></li><li>
<a href="#">Twitter</a></li><li>
<a href="#">MySpace</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you understand the problem now?

Comment: so u want the dropdown to remain of the same size , if the browser is minimised?

Comment: Please learn [indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Comment: can you put in jsfiddle please not getting the issue here

Comment: Snippets are only useful if at least `Run code snippet` will show a working demo  or `Copy snippet to answer` fully works. If you spread your code in two snippets neither `Run code snippet` nor `Copy snippet to answer` will work.

Comment: So how can i make it not resize the elements when browser size is changed?

Comment: Set a `width` using `px`. I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using a two different styles that would react to the Browser size changing.
float:left; and width:33%;

usually when sizing anything in CSS with a type of percentage leads to the percentage changing when the browser is re-sized so if you want your menu system to remain static when the browser size changes try to use more exact measurements try to get a precise Pixel measurement.

also When using float:left , float is a responsive style it tends to change with screen size so when there is not enough space for all the elements to fit in it will force them into a new line or compress somehow your could try using a flexbox solution or try hacking it with clever margins

but if you want your Menu system to remain relatively static but work on different browser/screen sizes try using Media queries to make the Styles work differently under different screen sizes.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer makes so much more sense :)